# Why does a new Date in Phonegap on iOS not return anything?

Tags: javascript, ios, date, cordova

Here is an example in Javascript which works well on Android but does not work for iOS. I don't know why?

```
showTime = function(timeId, time_incoming) {
    var curTime = new Date();
    var time_in = new Date(time_incoming);
    var curTimeStr = curTime.format('yy/mm/dd');
    var inTimeStr = time_in.format('yy/mm/dd');
    if (curTimeStr === inTimeStr)
    {
       $("#" + timeId).text(curTimeStr);
    }
    else
    {
        $("#" + timeId).text(inTimeStr);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Date` object in JavaScript has no `format` function.

Separately, re this line:

```
var time_in = new Date(time_incoming);
```

You haven't said what `time_incoming` is, but if it's a string, you need to be sure it's a string in a format that is actually supported. A lot of browsers add to the formats that are supported, but you can't rely on it. The only string format that's officially supported is [a simplified form of ISO 8601](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15), but that's relatively new (only specified a couple of years ago) and not present in older browsers. All desktop browsers also support `yyyy/mm/dd` (with slashes, not dashes), even though that's not specified. So if `time_incoming` is a string, you may need to parse it yourself.

Comment: @April: No idea, some extension perhaps.